# How to display product order by customer

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on an e-commerce website, I have a build login system for customers who can log in and order products.
My question is how to get all products order by customer and show them on seprate page

Here is what my data base look like

`Products` table

- title
- price
- sizes

`Cart` Table:

- id
- items
- expire_date
- paid
- shipped

`user` table

- id
- full_name

Comment: you should probably have an orders table that has a customer ID column in it.

Comment: That's probably more price columns than you really need

Comment: And a column called items sounds *really* ofd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use single word, all single, if you use plural, all plural:
If items means products, use product for less confusing:
And you possibly need one more table to hold details of order/cart

```
user    (id, created, updated, user_name,    ...)
product (id, created, updated, product_name, price, ...)
cart    (id, created, expired, user_id, status_id, ...)
cart_detail(id, cart_id, product_id, qty, price, ...)
cart_status(id, status) -- new / paid / cancelled / shipped / ...
```

Show all orders by a customer:

```
SELECT *
FROM cart
WHERE user_id = $customer_id
```